# How to pair with another BLE device using Ionic?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ionic3, ionic-native

so in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003983/how-to-identify-a-device-found-via-bluetooth-using-ble-for-ios/47016490#47016490) I asked how would I identify a bluetooth device after doing an scan. It seems that only those devices I have connected to show their name, all other devices are shown as `unnamed`.

So my question is, how do I pair all the unnamed devices using the [Ionic Native BLE library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/)? It doesn't matter if I need to do a manual process for each one (since this will be done only once). Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by pair? Are you asking about a regular connect or a Bluetooth gatt authentication using a passkey?

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, when you scan you get objects like this:

```
{
  id: "2BD5D5A7-EF50-B4F4-D4FD-9A8413006D4B",
  rssi: -24,
  advertising: {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable: true
  },
  name: ""
}
```

where name is an empty string which is your term `unnamed`.

You can check if the name is an empty string, take the `id` value instead to establish BLE connection.

```
ble.connect("2BD5D5A7-EF50-B4F4-D4FD-9A8413006D4B", connectSuccess, connectFailure);
```